# Using Jersey client (v1.18.1) - long HTTP response is cropped

Tags: jersey, client, response

I am using Jersey client v1.18.1.
I am executing a GET request to an API I have in BE.
Using sniffer, I see that the response is correctly reaching to the client side, but once the response is being parsed - it seems like the client cropped it (the resopnse is long in terms of content-size).
Is there a configuration I can use to enable long responses in the client?
Any other ideas?

Thanks

M.

Comment: Are you using the LoggingFilter to view the response or are you using a packet sniffer? Is the response large and if so is it being chunked?

Comment: Sorry for the delay with my response...

Comment: Sorry for the delay with my response...LoggingFilter is being used (com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LogginFilter). The response is large, yes. What do you mean by asking 'is it being chunked?'

Comment: For sure try setting the size of the LoggingFilter. I usually don't get anything more than the headers if I don't up the logging output size.

Answer (score 0):

I have to change the output of the logging size of the output filter. It won't show you much of anything unless you do something like this. The ~200k is pretty much overkill but it is not production code so I don't care.

```
public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RestApplication.class.getName());

public RestApplication() {
    registerInstances(new LoggingFilter(logger, 200000));
}
```